# What does 0 mean in this FOR loop

Tags: oracle, for-loop, plsql

```
FOR X IN 0.. NUM_OF_DAYS LOOP
```

What does the `0..` mean in PL/SQL

Comment: The fragment that has meaning is `IN 0..NUM_OF_DAYS`. `X` takes successively the values `0, 1, ..... , NUM_OF_DAYS`. If you are familiar with `for` loops in **any** language, you should understand this; `val_1 .. val_2` is the notation used in PL/SQL for the first and the last value in the loop (strangely, with **two** dots - not one, not three).

Comment: [FOR LOOP Statement in the PL/SQL reference manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/plsql-control-statements.html#GUID-C4BC9960-5945-4646-BBDE-DC00346F8702)

Answer (score 0):

It means loop will start from 0 and will increase through each iteration. Here is an example:

```
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..3 LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (TO_CHAR(i));
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Loop will continue while value if i is 1 to 3.